# Delete/Remove post title in blogger (in all the blog!)?

Tags: post, title, blogger

How to Delete/Remove post title in blogger (in all the blog! not just static pages only!)? i mean in regular posts also.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put in CSS [Go to Template, Customize, Advanced, Add CSS] or add this before `]]></b:skin>` tag in Edit Template HTML, Expand Widget Templates:

```
.post-title.entry-title {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: It is usually not the best idea to just hide content when you can just have the server not send it...

Answer (score 1):

DISPLAY:NONE is not typically advised, because Google may seem it as "Suspicious" manner for hidden keyword optimization.

Better, too EDIT HTML (under template) and put this line in comments (  ):

```
      <!--  <h3 class='post-title ....</h3>  -->
```

Comment: He could also just drop the line so that title isn't even sent with the response... but your idea is indeed better than just not displaying it through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Customize the theme, using the theme editor available in the blog dashboard. Opt to customize the theme. Look for the advanced options. Give the 'post title' element a transparent colour and a 0px font.

[image]

Specifically:

Go to your blog dashboard.
Select 'theme' from the list in the left pane, then 'customize' in the centre pain (pane? pain?).
Then select 'Advanced' on the left.
Select 'post title' from the list that appears in the main pane.
Click on text-colour dropdown and select 'transparent.'
And change the font to 0px as well.
Click 'apply to blog'.