# How to hide title from mobile version of blogger?

Tags: css, mobile, blogger

I am trying to hide titles in the mobile version of my blog (on blogger). I am trying this code in Advanced CSS but it is not working.

> .mobile-index-title.entry-title { display: none; }

Similarly if you do that for regular blog posts it work as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446056/delete-remove-post-title-in-blogger-in-all-the-blog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to template, under mobile click the setting button (wheel like), then select custom and save.

Then when you add the following line your title won't appear on the mobile site anymore:

> .mobile-index-title.entry-title { display: none; }

If you don't select custom, blogger won't parse your Advanced CSS section when showing in mobile mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it inside a `@media` query. Something like

```
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .mobile-index-title.entry-title { display: none; }
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mobile-index-title.entry-title { display: none; }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .mobile-index-title.entry-title { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding @media in the Advanced CSS section of blogger template. However, I don't think that blogger is reading the Advanced CSS section when showing on mobile devices. I am not sure though. Thanks for your answer though